# Accessing StdClass value with colon :protected

Tags: php, stdclass

How do I access the value of stdClass with colon ":protected"?

For example, I had this $obj with these result :

```
object(Google_Service_Plus_PeopleFeed)#14 (11) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(30) "Google+ List of Visible People"
  ["totalItems"]=>
  int(4)
  ["collection_key:protected"]=>
  string(5) "items"
  ["data:protected"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["items"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(7) {
        ["kind"]=>
        string(11) "plus#person"
        ["etag"]=>
        string(57) ""42gOj_aEQqJGtTB3WnOUT5yUTkI/1eNkvlfeTwXXldr9rYAvMcwM6bk""
        ["objectType"]=>
        string(6) "person"
```

For example, I tried to access "kind" value which is "plus#person" using these code :

```
$kind = $obj->{'data:protected'}->items[0]->kind; //-> returns NULL
//OR
$kind = $obj->{data:protected}->items[0]->kind; //->returns error on ":"
```

Well, they don't seems to work...Any idea how to access that protected data?

Thanks

Comment: Aren't there any accessors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a `stdClass` object, it's an object of the class `Google_Service_Plus_PeopleFeed`. You cannot access protected properties of a class [easily]. If the class doesn't want you to access the data, then you shouldn't. But typically the class offers some method you can call to get the data, like `$obj->getData()` or some such. Look at the class definition or its documentation to see how you're supposed to use the class.

Comment: I see. So from what I got, I need to find out the method to access the protected data within the class right? Thanks

Comment: This is not 100% correct. You can access the protected members of the class in different ways! You can use Reflection, or you can subclass or you can even use a closure. See my answer.

Comment: @Mathias Sure, there are any number of way to work around "protected" properties. **But you shouldn't.** They're marked as `protected` for a reason. Unless you absolutely know what you're doing, you should use the *public API* which is sure to exist if you're supposed to access that data.

Comment: True. Maybe you should put this in your answer - I think "no way at all" is misleading. And in certain circumstances people might be urged to access protected variables - (e.g. to work around a bug inside a framework, etc) - and for these cases I added a possibe solution.

Comment: OK, fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access to a protected property from outside this object. Look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can finally access it with :

```
$kind = $obj['data']['items'][0]['kinds'];
```

Anybody can explain why? Just curious why it needs to be protected >.<

Comment: That means the class is implementing the `ArrayAccess` interface, so you can access it like an array. There's probably still a getter method somewhere though.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there is probably a reason that these properties are protected, so you should think twice before trying to access them.

If you need to access protected variables, you could use Reflection, but there might be an easier solution. By binding a closure to the object, you should be able to access the protected variables from the closure:

```
class X {
   protected $a = 10;
   public $b = 20; 
}


$closure = function() {
          return get_object_vars($this);
};

$result = Closure::bind($closure, new X(), 'X');
var_dump($result());
```